# Animation not working in styled-component using {keyframes}

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have a base component - Emoji.jsx

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const StyledEmoji = styled.div`
    font-size: 6rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    &:not(:last-child) {
        margin-right: 3rem;
    }
`;

function Emoji({ content, handleClick }) {
    return (
        <StyledEmoji onClick={() => handleClick(content)}>{content}</StyledEmoji>
    );
}

export default Emoji;
```

I am extending this component and applying anmimation to it in EmojiBubble.jsx

```
import Emoji from './Emoji';
import styled, { keyframes } from 'styled-components';

const Bubble = keyframes`
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
`;

const EmojiBubble = styled(Emoji)`
    animation: ${Bubble} 6s ease-in-out;
`;

export default EmojiBubble;
```

But, the animation is not working when I am using EmojiBubble component

```
<EmojiBubble content={emoji} /> //Emoji not rotating
```

What the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

`function Emoji({ content, handleClick })...` doesn't pass the class name down to `StyledEmoji`, that's why styles created by `EmojiBubble` are not applied. All you need to do: pass the class name:

```
function Emoji({ content, handleClick, className }) {
  return (
    <StyledEmoji className={className} onClick={() => handleClick(content)}>
      {content}
    </StyledEmoji>
  );
}
```

[Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/q-63009097-conditionstyled-o5rmo?file=/index.js)